# Float isn't floating correctly

Tags: html, css

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bn2w47o7/

I want to put 3 divs in one line and then a new line. The link above is one of my tries, in my opinion all the divs should float in a line, but as you can see in the fiddle it isn't.

Here is the Code:

```css
.teaser {
  width: 32.33%;
  margin: 0 1% 20px 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.teaser:nth-child(3n+0) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="kategorie">Kat</div>

  <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>

  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="teaser">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="kategorie">Kat</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>

  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut .</div>
</div>

<div class="teaser">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="kategorie">Kat</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Three</a></h3>

  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="teaser">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="kategorie">Kat</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Four</a></h3>

  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita</div>
</div>

<div class="teaser">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="kategorie">Kat</div>

  <h3><a href="#">Five</a></h3>

  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametet ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is though you haven't used a CSS Reset or `box-sizing:border-box` - https://jsfiddle.net/3c1h81nk/

Comment: @Pete,Okay, i removed it.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I'm so sorry, I had added this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.teaser:nth-child(3) {border: 1px solid red;} The width and margin make it 99.9% overall, the border here is taking the combined width over this point and it is wrapping, remove the border and it is fine (reduce the width or margin otherwise).

Comment: I just tried this, this is not working at all. the divs are floating happily around, sometimes 1 in a line, sometimes 3.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? I opened your fiddle deleted the border and it's floating in sets of three as expected.

Comment: I just put this on the website, in fiddle it is working. But on the site not, although it is the same code.

Comment: Can you give a more accurate example of the css? I've found the issue on the fiddle but need more info it that isn't the problem on the site.

Comment: You have got the whole CSS and the whole html code of the divs, there is just another content.

Comment: Well using  box-sizing: border-box; on .teaser is another solution if that helps. If the fiddle is a representation of your issue and the fix to that doesn't fix your issue, there must be something else on your site.

Comment: Could be the different height of the divs the reason?

Comment: Yes that could definitely be the case, if the element above is encroaching on the area of the other one then it will be pushed along. Could you update the fiddle to cause the issue and I can try and help further?

Comment: Okay, I added a min-width: 600 and now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from the margins associated with each teaser div. You'll need to have a lower width value for .teaser to compensate for the extra margin space. I messed about with your jsfiddle and managed to get three in a row by having a width of around 30%:

```css
.teaser {
 width: 30.33%;
 margin: 0 1% 20px 0;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cn5xvoL0/)

Comment: this is very mysterious. on the Website, there are many more divs, but the fourth, the nineth and19th and the 23th, and the 27th and many others without any connection are the only one in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
.teaser {float:left; text-align:center; margin-right:20px; width:18%;}
```

Change your .teaser css with the above css given and you will find out all the `<div>` in one line. If you want to do 3 `<div>` in one line and rest in second line that give **width:30%;** to the **.teaser** class, and you will find your required output.